# I've installed a package via npm - wt is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have issues when I try to run a package installed via `npm`. Package controls orphans and widows on both document ready as well as window resize - which is exactly what I'm looking for.

1) I've installed the plugin via `npm i widowtamer-npm --save`.

2) I've made an import via `import 'widowtamer-npm';` where I successfully import other packages.

3) [According to the documentation](https://github.com/nathanford/widowadjust), in the other file where I do all the JS logic I wrote:

```
wt.fix({
    elements: 'h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6',
    chars: 20,
    method: 'nbsp',
    event: 'resize'
});
```

Unfortunately as soon as I refresh the page, console gives me

> ReferenceError: wt is not defined`,

pointing to `wt.fix(` line. I thought that maybe assigning to window.wt would fix it.

```
import wt from 'widowtamer-npm';
window.wt = wt;
```

But then when I do `npm run dev` I get:

> "export 'default' (imported as 'wt') was not found in 'widowtamer-npm'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing this in node.js?

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into windowtamer.js file

[image]

export is  in this format `export {wt}`

in order for  `import wt from 'widowtamer-npm'` to work it should be like `export default wt;`

so try

```
import {wt} from 'widowtamer-npm';
```